# How to increase the performance when updating a large table in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using Azure Table Storage to store around a million records of mappings information, e.g. <trackId, profileId>. Those mapping information should be updated monthly by sending a query to an API endpoint. I wrote the following codes to do a simply check for each record and update the record stored in the storage.

```
public void updateTrackProfileIdMappings() {
    List<TrackProfileIdMapping> mappings = trackProfileIdMappingRepository.getAllMappings();

    logger.info("Start updating TrackProfileIdMappings. {} mappings will be checked.", mappings.size());
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
    int count = 0;
    for (TrackProfileIdMapping mapping : mappings) {
        String trackId = mapping.getTrackId();
        count = updateTrackProfileIdMapping(trackId, count);

        if(countTrackProfileIdMappingUpdate % 10000 == 0) {
            logger.info("Updating TrackProfileIdMappings: {} out of {} mappings have been checked and updated.", countTrackProfileIdMappingUpdate, mappings.size());
        }
    }
    stopwatch.stop();

    logger.info("Finished updating TrackProfileIdMappings. {} mappings have been checked and updated.", mappings.size());
}


private int updateTrackProfileIdMapping(String trackId, int count) {
    try {
        String profileId = ApiService.getProfileId(trackId);
        trackProfileIdMappingRepository.insertOrUpdateMapping(trackId, profileId);
        count++;
    } catch (.ApiCallException e) {
        logger.error("Failed to retrieve profileId for trackId {}", trackId);
    }
}
```

While it took almost 30 minutes to update record 10k records. Is there a way to use multi-thread to increase the performance in Java?

Comment: At the very least you could run everything in a transaction so that you don't have to re-connect for every db statement.

Comment: you could wrap updateTrackProfileIdMapping in a Runnable and then use Thgread Pool to process it concurrently